# How to use the value of a running pace in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: string, format, libreoffice-calc

So basically, I have a sheet where speeds in kilometers per hour (km/h) are written in cells.
I sometimes convert these speeds into paces (in minutes per kilometer (mn/km)).
To do so, I apply the integer function to an inverse function used on the speed divided by 60 -> INT(1/(speedCell/60)). This gives me the minutes part of the pace.
For example, let's admit that I have a speed of 13 km/h; the pace of that speed is 4'36/km.
The formula gives me the minutes : `=INT(1/(13/60)) -> 4`.

Now I need to get the seconds part. I do it using the truncate function over the subtraction of the speed converted directly into a pace and the integer part of the pace.
Formula applied : `=TRUNC((1/(13/60)-INT(1/(13/60)))*60) -> 36`.
Simplified, this is : `=PACE(minutes and seconds)-PACE(minutes) -> seconds`.

**Here comes the problem**. I format these two formulas into : `=FORMULA1&"'"&FORMULA2"/km"`.
My question is : How can I use the result, now that it is being formatted with a string in the middle of the formula?

I used to use the format styling to add a unit behind the value; but since there is an apostrophe in the middle of the formula, I don't know how to do it.

Thank you for your help, don't hesitate to ask, if you have questions over the understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly. But instead of concatenating the pace parts "manually", I recommend building a time value from the minutes / seconds values using the [TIME(hours ; minutes ; seconds)](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/func_time.html?&DbPAR=CALC&System=WIN) function. Now, you can use the cell formatting templates to generate an output like [min]'[sec]/km with the following format code

> `MM'SS"/km"`

and do calculations.

BTW: you could also use the MOD() function to get the seconds part:

> `=INT(MOD((1/(13/60));1)*60)`

Comment: Oh nice, that's so cool, thank you for bringing your light my way (it works)! I didn't know the existence of that function. Actually I'm a complete newbie ahah. I'm learning new things every day! :p I really can't understand what MOD does, I'm just really not used to that...

Comment: MOD() allows for [Modulo Operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). MOD() returns the remainder when one integer is divided by another. MOD(2;2) returns 0, since there's no remainder; MOD(3;2) returns 1; MOD(4;2)=0, MOD(5;2)=1 and so on. MOD(value;1) returns the part of `value` after the decimal separator.